# PDF printer that can be controlled by .NET (exporting from Maptitude)

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, maptitude

In my current project, I created an automatic process that controls the Maptitude application, and prints the results to PDFs using Maptitude's API.

The problem is that Maptitude neither has an option to save the outcome to PDF, nor return the outcome as an object. Therefore I worked around this by installing a **pdf printer**, and gave the command to Maptitude in C# to **print** using that pdf printer. However, even with this approach, the the pdf printer pops up a prompt asking for output destination and stopping the automation.

For that reason, I'm trying to find an pdf printer that have an API for .Net, or at least does not give any prompt when print. Does such pdf printer exist?

**Maptitude is a GIS**

Comment: I note the comments to close, but the OP has tried a programming approach, and I still think a programming approach is possible - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BullZip PDFprinter may work without prompt on a single file.
See [BullZip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php)

Comment: I tried BullZip as your recommendation, it does have option to print out quietly with the preset configuration. To avoid getting overwrite the old pdf file in the second iteration, I think I'll just simply changing the files names in c# right after create them. This gonna be my "hammer" to get out of the stuck. Thank you very much.

Comment: Another possibility is update the PDF printer configuration file before printing by changing the output filename in BullZip settings. Update the PDF printer configuration file C:\Users\theusername\AppData\Roaming\PDF Writer\Bullzip PDF Printer\settings.ini

Answer (score 0):

The Maptitude API has a number of ways of getting a map out of Maptitude - including **as an object**. Look in the SDK documentation, specifically under  `CopyMapToClipboard`, `CopyMapToOLE`, `SaveMapToMetafile` and/or `SaveMapToBitmap()` functions. These are all accessible through GISDK, the COM interface, and .NET.

You can then import these into your PDF if that is what you want (the user documentation recommends this approach for chart->PDF exports).