# How do I generate a PDF file in C#.Net that displays SQL records?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf-generation

I am developing an *Inventory Management System*(Window Forms). 
I have a *.Net windows form* that displays a list of all the orders made (*in a dataGridView*).
The task is to provide the option to print, or email the PDF version of the details of an order. It contains plain text (such as greetings) and values from SQL Server tables(such as Order No., Date, List of Items)

I am trying to figure out the best way to do it.

It seems sensible to generate the PDF when the user selects an order, rather than creating and saving the PDF for all orders. 
But I am struggling to find out how to I proceed.

Comment: There is no built-in way of producing a PDF from .NET. You'll need to use a third-party library. Do some research to determine which library you'd like to use and how to use it.

Comment: A solution is to install a (free) Pdf printer and print your pages to this printer. BullZip printer allows you to do that without any prompt. More details in [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876459/pdf-printer-that-can-be-controlled-by-net-exporting-from-maptitude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is too broad and opinion based. But there are generally few ways this can be done

1. Excel interop (or even Word) - load excel with your data and call excel print to pdf
2. Usually, report libraries like Crystal Reports or others, provide "save as pdf" option.
3. Create a file (in whatever format) and use pdf printer, which is software printer that you install and call from your code. there are free such printers.
4. Use a specialized library like iTextSharp to create your pdf in code
5. No doubt - there is such online service where you can convert your file

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ExportToPDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the data from database into datatable

    string strQuery = "select CustomerID, ContactName, City, PostalCode" +
        " from customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    //Create a dummy GridView

    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Comment: May be you should explain how this related to Windows forms?